# Integration between two SFDC Orgs through middleware

Tags: integration, wsdl

**We have a requirement :**

- Org 1 contains Account data
- Org 2 needs to have a VF page where data of Account will be displayed on real time . User can also make some changes and save back which needs to be updated in Org 1.

**Solution Options :**

- Update fields from Org 1 to Org 2 through partner WSDL through middleware .
- Send the updated fields back to Org 1 through Outbound message.

Are these viable solution options? Are there others we should consider?

Comment: Seems primarily opinion based...

Comment: We are doing something like this in my current project to connect two salesforce orgs using snaplogic using REST protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your best solution will be implementing MDM such as Informatica which has SF connector available. Also it allows you to update the information from any source and have real time or schedule update as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Salesforce Connect aka Lightning Connect.

Salesforce connect will allow you to fetch external objects in your org where VF pages are. The VF page's controller can even querry data like normal SOQL and the data will be fetched realtime from other SF org.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=xorg_adapter_about.htm&language=en_US&type=0

Its native to salesforce and out of the box solution, so would be my first preference.

Comment: Hi Pranay . Thanks for the suggestion . However the client architecture requires the integration through Tibco only . Can you please suggest

Comment: Keep in mind that Salesforce Connect is a paid feature.